# Passing JSON to a C# method with Dictionary<int, List<int>> as parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have trouble sending JSON data in correct format to this C# method:

```
public bool MyMethod(int foo, Dictionary<int, List<int>> bar)
```

What I don't know is to format the `bar` variable:

```
var bar = {};
bar['1'] = [1, [1, 2]];
bar['2'] = [1, [1, 2, 3]];
bar['3'] = [1, [1, 2]];

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: '{"foo":1, "bar":' + JSON.stringify(bar) + '}'
});
```

.NET gives me a ´InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary is not supported for
serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.
```

Comment: What Serializer are you using? if you are using the default .net serialize I recommend you use JSON serializer which handles dictionary serializations and more efficient than the default one.

Comment: As you are using ajax to send the json object try this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773102/Redirect-and-Post-JSON-Object-in-ASP-NET-MVC you may just replace the default JavasScriptSerializer with NewtonSoft JSON Serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried quick reverse-engineering for this and got this:

Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Code:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>{
                {0, new List<int>{1,2}},
                {1, new List<int>{3,4}}
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            ViewBag.Message = serializer.Serialize(dict);
```

When you change it to Dictionary< string , List < int> > it works:

Json: {"0":[1,2],"1":[3,4]}

You can of course later parse those strings to ints if you need.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Changes needed: `var bar = { "0":[1,2], "1":[3,4] };` and `public bool SubmitEducationReply(int educationId, Dictionary<string, List<int>> questionandanswers)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [NewtonSoft](http://james.newtonking.com/json) json converter:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>{
                {0, new List<int>{1,2}},
                {1, new List<int>{3,4}}
            };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
// json = {"0":[1,2],"1":[3,4]}
```

so you shouldn't have any issues with it.